# Problema al aplicar padding a un elemento select

Tags: bootstrap-4, html-select

Tengo un formulario con varios campos input formateados de esta forma con clases boostrap que funcionan correctamente.

```
<input class="form-control py-4" placeholder="Introduzca nombre completo del usuario" required name="name" type="text" id="name">
```

Pero si intento aplicar estas clases a una etiqueta "select" no funciona bien. Cualquier cosa que selecciono de la select no se visualiza en el campo. En cambio si se elimina py-4 se visualiza la opción seleccionada correctamente aunque lógicamente el campo tiene una menor altura que es lo que conseguía con py-4

```
<select class="form-control py-4" name="role_id" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Seleccionar rol--</option>                                                                                             
        <option value="1">Administrador</option>                                                                                              
        <option value="2">Autor</option>
        <option value="3">Suscriptor</option>
</select>
```

¿Por qué no está funcionando bien la clase py-4 en la select ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que las clases que pretendes usar son mutuamente excluyentes, es decir, la clase `form-control` aplica su propio valor de altura sobre el elemento:

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px); /* AQUÍ se establece un valor para la altura del elemento*/
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Si a ese elemento, además, le aplicas una regla de `padding` no compatible (`py-4`), el resultado es que no se vea correctamente el texto en el contenedor.

```css
.pb-4, .py-4 {
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem!important;
}
.pt-4, .py-4 {
    padding-top: 1.5rem!important;
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es que apliques una regla propia para este caso particular (si realmente es lo que pretendes hacer con el contenedor de tu elemento `select`).

Por ejemplo, podrías agregar una clase llamada `custom-auto-height` donde establezcas la altura del elemento a `auto`, con la declaración `!important`, para que tome precedencia sobre las clases de Bootstrap aplicadas sobre el mismo elemento:

```css
.custom-auto-height {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

y añadirla a tu elemento `select` como última clase en la cadena de clases (Estilos en Cascada):

```css
.custom-auto-height {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<select class="form-control py-4 custom-auto-height" name="role_id" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>--Seleccionar rol--</option>                                                   <option value="1">Administrador</option>                   <option value="2">Autor</option>
  <option value="3">Suscriptor</option>
</select>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracías por esta respuesta que me alerta ante posibles incompatibilidades entre clases de boostrap que yo desconocía. No obstante sigo sin entender porque esa incompatibilidad no se produce en campos Input y si en campos select. Además tu solución me genera un campo de tamaño significativamente más grande que el resto de campos input después de aplicar las clases form-control py-4. Pero si me has dado una idea pata crear esta clase .py-select{
    padding-bottom: 0.8rem !important;
    padding-top: 0.8rem !important;
    font-size: 0.9rem !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

Comment: Claro, para poder mostrar correctamente el texto, con el `padding` que le estás aplicando, hay que aumentar el tamaño del elemento `select`. Ahora, si lo que quieres es mantener el tamaño, no le des un `padding` tan grande. Todo es cuestión de lo que necesites hacer.